# Python: Read Write

Tags: python, string, file

i am new to Python and am having trouble with this problem.  Thanks in advance.

Generate a list of strings of size 10  where each element is a
string made up of * characters and length runs from 1 to 10
Write these strings to a text file. Be sure to terminate each string with end of line character, i.e. '\n'
Use context manager syntax for writing, i.e. "with" keyword
Hint: open file in 'wt' mode for writing.

Instead of using writelines() or write(),  use print() function.
Hint: print() function has an argument file.

Open the same file for reading and read back all the lines in the file you have just created
Do not use context manager when reading the file back.
'''

This is what i have so far:

```
strings = ['*', '**', '***', '****', '*****', '******', '*******', '********', '*********', '**********']
f = open("file.out", 'w')
data = '\n'.join(strings) # Concat all strings in list, separated by line break
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

Comment: google python stdout

Comment: It tells you exactly the steps involves, you have not implemented `Use context manager syntax for writing, i.e. "with" keyword` at all. You don't use `print` either to write to the file.

Comment: Did you actually look at the dupe? It literally shows you exactly how to redirect to a file using print more than once

Answer (score -1):

To print out the lines 1 by 1:

```
strings = ['*', '**', '***', '****', '*****', '******', '*******', '********', '*********', '**********']
f = open("Delete me", 'w+')
data = '\n'.join(strings) # Concat all strings in list, separated by line break
f.write(data)
f.close()

def read():
    f = open("Delete me", 'r')
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

And just call read() to read the file